# How in Intellij IDEA in new HTTP Client automate parse Response

Tags: intellij-idea

I couldn't find how to automate parse responce and use in next GET request

```
###
POST http://localhost/coolsoftware/rest/authentication?login=username&password=1234
---- response will be
…
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=028EBF489BDF2D88A8A70935F4CA7C04; <-- I need this
…

###
GET http://localhost/coolsoftware/rest/bills/
Cookie: JSESSIONID=028EBF489BDF2D88A8A70935F4CA7C04; <-- to use here
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
POST http://localhost/coolsoftware/rest/authentication?login=username&password=1234

> {% client.global.set("yourVariable", response.headers.valueOf('Set-Cookie')); %}
```

And then:

```
GET http://localhost/coolsoftware/rest/bills/
Cookie: {{yourVariable}}
```

If there are more than one Set-Cookie header, you should use `valuesOf()` instead ([available](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-42311) in the latest EAP), and then iterate through the array assigning vars.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you add that to your documentation on JetBrains, I've been digging and didn't find it.

Comment: Pinged our tech writer, should be available with 2018.3 docs when it's released

Comment: @EugeneMorozov 2019 https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html#open-requests-collection and still no where to find it

Comment: @gajo Please check [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-response-handling-examples.html) page.

Comment: If you guys want to execute those http request files without using IntelliJ IDEA (such as in Jenkins CI) you can use the intellij-rest-cli https://github.com/quangson91/intellij_rest_cli which is support run http request files from command-line.